# Jolokia-agent cannot find path

Tags: activemq-classic, jolokia

I'm having some problems setting up ActiveMQ. The `jolokia-access.xml` file cannot be found. I received the following error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the file `C:\Appl\apache\apache-activemq-5.17.1\conf\jolokia-access.xml` exist?

Comment: I managed to fix it. I had to make some changes to my `activemq.xml`. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Late but at least a working solution to the above issue.  I had exactly the same issue whereby the ActiveMQ log reported not finding ../conf/jolokia-access.xml due to stripping out the path dividers and therefore not finding the file.  This issue persists even up to apache-activemq-5.18.1

The fix was to simply provide absolute paths for the environment vars in the

> D:\ActiveMQ\bin\win64\wrapper.conf

file as below:

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************

# wrapper.debug=TRUE
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_HOME="D:/ActiveMQ/"
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_BASE="D:/ActiveMQ/"
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_CONF="D:/ActiveMQ/conf"
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_DATA="D:/ActiveMQ/data"
```

This completely fixed the issue.  NOTE: I extract my ActiveMQ from its default versioned directory so I can maintain my absolute path with each upgrade.

Comment: I don't understand why my post was edited on April 21 to remove the personal comment and regards.  Please help me understand this.

Answer (score -1):

Had problems with my `activemq.xml`. Was able to run ActiveMQ after making a few changes to the config.

Comment: This answer is vague. What changes did you make?